# Sonata Admin Bundle - Different field options in configureFormFields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, mode, symfony-sonata

Is there a possiblity to add different fields to a Sonata Admin Bundle Form depending on wether you're creating a new entity or editing an existing one in configureFormFields?

Comment: You most likely want to use the [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way witch is recommended by the officiel documentation ( [Click here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_dynamic_form_modification.html) )

```
$subject = $this->getSubject();

if ($subject->isNew()) {
    $formMapper->add('customField', TextType::class);
}
```

or you can do:

```
if ($this->isCurrentRoute('create')) {
    $formMapper->add('name', TextType::class);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I've accomplished this using:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{
    // Add fields common to add AND edit...

    if ($this->getSubject()->getId() > 0) {
        // Add fields only when editing an existing object
    }
}
```

Obviously you could add an `else` condition too if you want to only be able to add fields for a new object.

Comment: is there a way to do the same in case of embedded admins? I am using sonata_type_collection and want to do the same with one of the child table fields. Thanks

Comment: @GBRocks from my experience this is not possible, the subject reference does not relate to the row (especially when saving)